# JSON Parsing not giving Proper NSMutable Array :

Tags: iphone, ios, json, web-services

I am working on one Webservice app .

They give me response like :

**JSON RESPONSE:**

> {"1":"03:30 PM To 04:30 PM","2":"01:30 PM To 02:30 PM","3":"02:30 AM
>   To 03:30 PM","4":"04:30 PM To 05:30 PM","5":"05:30 PM To 06:30
>   PM","6":"06:30 PM To 07:30 PM"}

And I want to Show all this **TIME** intervel with Check box in my another View controller so User can select it .

How do I get this ...

Need help

Comment: To get an array it would need to have [] brackets around the array. componentsSeparatedByString as described below should work.

Comment: check my answer and if you got any problem then ask me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply parse the JSON by following Method

```
NSString* strJSONResponse = @"{\"1\":\"03:30 PM To 04:30 PM\",\"2\":\"01:30 PM To 02:30 PM\",\"3\":\"02:30 AM To 03:30 PM\",\"4\":\"04:30 PM To 05:30 PM\",\"5\":\"05:30 PM To 06:30 PM\",\"6\":\"06:30 PM To 07:30 PM\"}";

NSDictionary* dataDict = [strJSONResponse JSONValue];

NSLog(@"%@",dataDict);
```

Here is the output:

```
Printing description of dataDict:
{
    1 = "03:30 PM To 04:30 PM";
    2 = "01:30 PM To 02:30 PM";
    3 = "02:30 AM To 03:30 PM";
    4 = "04:30 PM To 05:30 PM";
    5 = "05:30 PM To 06:30 PM";
    6 = "06:30 PM To 07:30 PM";
}
```

With this dictionary you can simply make use as per your requirement.

Here you will need to include Required classes for SBJSON found [here](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

I had to add "\" as an escape characters to use it as a string.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation for `NSArray componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)`. This will separate the Json reply into an array at the string you specify. I would probably use @",".

Answer (score 1):

You can use SBJson classes to parse json data,

here is the like to get all classes

[SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)